# How to move file from another directory to created folder that make by name file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I already make script file for make new folder base on file name and move 1 file to this folder. The code as below.

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "sourcedir=C:\Users\XXX\4_MapIdentifyAndCSV"
set "destdir=C:\Users\XXX\5_OldData"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\*.csv" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1 delims=." %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        md "%DestDir%\%%B" 2>nul
        move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%B\"  
    )
)

endlocal
```

But I want to move another files from another directory to created folder too.

Example:
At C:\Users\XXX\2_Video move all file video to crated folder.

At C:\Users\XXX\Sub_Folder move all of Sub_Folder to crated folder.

And at C:\Users\XXX\3_Txt move all Text file to crated folder.

Please supporting me.

Comment: Open `cmd` and type `robocopy /?` you'll find it very straight forward to copy directory structures from source to destination. Also, there is a variable called `%userprofile%` which can replace your ```C:\users\xxx\``` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "sourcedir=U:\Users\XXX"
set "destdir=U:\Users\XXX\5_OldData"

FOR %%s IN ("4_MapIdentifyAndCSV:.csv" "2_Video" "Sub_Folder" "3_Txt") DO FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%t IN (%%s) DO (

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\%%t\*%%u" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        ECHO md "%DestDir%\%%B" 2>nul
        ECHO move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%t\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%B\"  
    )
)
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I use `U:` for testing.

The `eol=|` is not required in your code, so I removed it.

The extra "shell" using `%%s`..`%%u` works this way:

The quoted string from the list is assigned to `%%s`. Each entry in the list is `"subdirectoryname:filemask"`. `:` is chosen because it can't appear in either a subdirectory name or a filemask. The `for ... delims=:...` assigns the subdirectory name to `%%t` and the filemask to `%%u`. If the filemask is not provided, `%%u` will be *empty*.

From there, it's just a matter of piecing together the appropriate parts of the filenames and directories required, inserting `*` before the filemask to specify "all".

In this way, you can control the filetypes moved if required. It would appear that you want only the `.csv` files from one directory and all files from the others. You could also specify `"4_MapIdentifyAndCSV:.csv" "4_MapIdentifyAndCSV:.xyz"` within the list to move all `.csv` and all `.xyz` files if you wanted *that*.

Please note that the `md` and `move` commands ar merely `echo`ed for testing purposes. Remove the `echo` keyword from each of those lines to activate the create/move.

---

I am not sure that I understand the requirements.

By modifying the list so that each element is

```
source_subdir:destination_subdir:filemask
```

we can achieve

4_map...*.csv -> 5_olddata\filename\filename.csv
2_vid...*     -> 5_olddata\dest...2_vid...*
sub_f...*     -> 5_olddata\dest...sub_f...*
3_txt...*     -> 5_olddata\dest...3_txt...*

Of course, the *actual* destination subdirectory *could* be `common` if required - all that would be required is that the second element becomes `common`.

The `.csv` destination for the `4_map...` source is derived from OP's original code.

Note that the *destination_subdir* must be a single space as a sequence of delimiters is processed as a single delimiter (`:` = `::` = `:::::::`)

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "sourcedir=U:\Users\XXX"
set "destdir=U:\Users\XXX\5_OldData"

FOR %%s IN ("4_MapIdentifyAndCSV: :.csv" "2_Video:dest_for_2_video" "Sub_Folder:dest_for_sub_folder" "3_Txt:dest_for_3_text") DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%t IN (%%s) DO (

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\%%t\*%%v" 2^>nul') do (
  IF "%%u"==" " (
    rem if second element of list item is "empty", destination is directory ...\filename
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        ECHO md "%DestDir%\%%B" 2>nul
        ECHO move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%t\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%B\"  
    )
  ) ELSE (
    rem if second element of list item is not "empty" it is the destination directory ...\%%u
    ECHO md "%DestDir%\%%u" 2>nul
    ECHO move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%t\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%u\"  
  )
)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for great support. I used your code and quite work but result is separate 3 folders following difference name. I'd like to get  1 folder for folder "2_Video", "Sub_Folder", "3_Txt" save in 4_MapIdentifyAndCSV:.csv folder. please help me again.

Comment: Oh! Great, you help me very well close to success. Please help me just 1 thing. How can I change to move destination. 

from..... (2_vid...* -> 5_olddata\dest...2_vid...*) .......to...... (2_vid...* -> (5_olddata\filenameceatedfolder_from(4_map...*.csv)\dest...2_vid...*

from.......(sub_f...* -> 5_olddata\dest...sub_f...*).....to.....(5_olddata\firstfilenameceatedfolder(4_map...*.csv)\dest...sub_f...*)

from....(3_txt...* -> 5_olddata\dest...3_txt...*) .....to......(3_txt...* -> 5_olddata\firstfilenameceatedfolder(4_map...*.csv)\dest...3_txt...*)

Please supporting me.